# Javascript : Submitting a form outside the actual form doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to achieve a fairly easy triggering mechanism for deleting multiple items from a tablegrid. If a user has enough access he/she is able to delete multiple users from a table. In the table I have set up checkboxes, one per row/user. The name of the checkboxes is `UsersToDeletep[]`, and the value per row is the unique `UserID`.

When a user clicks the button 'Delete selected users' a simple validation takes place to make sure at least one checkbox is selected. After that I call my simple function `Submit(form)`. The function works perfectly when called within the `form`-tags, where I also use it to delete a single user.

The function:

```
function Submit(form)
{   
    document.forms[form].submit();
}
```

I've also alerted `document.forms[form]`. The result is, as expected `[object HTMLFormElement]`. But for some reason the form just won't submit and a pagereload takes place. I'm a bit confused and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

### Update

As requested: the calling-code:

The code placed within `onclick="javascript:"`:

```
if(CheckMinimumCheckedCheckboxes('FormUserList', 1) == true)
{ 
    if(confirm('Weet u zeker dat u de geselecteerde gebruiker(s) wilt verwijderen?')) 
    { 
        Submit('FormUserList'); 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    alert('U dient minimaal 1 gebruiker te selecteren welke u wilt verwijderen.'); 
}
```

Separate functions in an external JS-file.

```
function CheckMinimumCheckedCheckboxes(formName, minAmount)
{
    var totalChecked = 0;
    var totalElements = document.forms[formName].length;

    for(i = 0; i < totalElements; i++)
    {
        if(document.forms[formName][i].checked == true)     
        {
            totalChecked++;
        }
    }

    if(totalChecked >= minAmount)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function Submit(form)
{   
    document.getElementById(form).submit();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that calls the function above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Never, ever, ever place an empty 'href=""' in your links and think you will fill it in later while later you decide to handle the link-element by an onclick-eventhandler... Seriously, it can save you hours of silly testing. :/**

Answer (score 1):

Try using the getElementById() Method:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp

```
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it didn't resolve in a working solution.

Comment: You need to add an ID attribute to your form tag.

<form name="frm1" id="frm1"> and then call that name in the getElementById() method.  The document.getElementById(form).submit(); won't work unless you have a var named form.  If you name your form "form" then you need to reference it in the  getElementById() mehtod as string document.getElementById("form").submit();  It looks like you referenced it as a scalar variable.

Comment: I pass it into the function (called from the page). then in the external js-file the functionparameter is passed into getElementById(parameterName). And ofcourse I've added an ID attribute to the form ;) But, it didn't work.

Comment: You may also try using jQuery to make your life a little easier.  You'd iterate through your forms using the .each() method:  $("form").each(...);

http://api.jquery.com/each/

and call the .submit() method on each reference 

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Thanks for afterreplying with a helpfull tip! +1 for your answer and comment. Thanks for the effort you made!